# Why does Magento 2 download "blank.html" file

Tags: magento2, category

Every time I go to Products > Categories I get a "blank.html" file downloaded to my local machine. Then, as I setup categories and click the Save Category button another "blank.html" file downloads to my local machine.

Here is a screen shot of what happens when I go to the Categories section of the backend (notice all the download "blank.html" files in the browser status bar) --> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bytqhoir_Tt5dFYwcUxGeExGUHM

Here is a screen shot of my downloads folder on my local machine --> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bytqhoir_Tt5SDU5b3FjZVdmYkE

How to shut that feature off?

Comment: Same question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98709/magento2-when-i-go-products-categories-browser-download-blank-html-file-a

Answer (score 1):

Looks like problem in web server configuration. Server returns wrong Content type header and as result file is downloaded instead of showing.

Comment: Then why or how does it only happen with Product Categories @KAndy?